# custom excerpt is not being shown

Tags: wp-query, excerpt

I am trying to show custom excerpt using the_excerpt(). the full code is as follows:

```
<div id="content">
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post', // You can add a custom post type if you like
    'paged' => $paged,
    'category_name'    => 'technology',
    'posts_per_page' => 10 // limit of posts
));

if ( have_posts() ){
  $i = 0;
  while ( have_posts() ) :
    $i++;
    the_post();
?>
  <?php if($i%2 == 1){?>
<div class="row">
<?php } ?>


<div class="col-md-6">
  <h3><a class="card-link" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php  the_field('title_for_excerpt'); ?> </a> </h3>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'rounded featured-image')); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 ">
     <div class="exceprt-container"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </div>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">বিস্তারিত </a>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
  <?php if($i%2 == 0){?>
  </div>
<?php }
 endwhile;
 if($i%2 == 1){?>
   </div>
<?php }
} ?> <!-- END have-post -->
<?php
```

But strange is: the excerpt is printing part of the actual content. But I input custom excerpt separately:
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can be happening is if you have added a Read more tag in your content it is overriding the manual excerpt. just check and see if you have `<!--more-->` tag in your content body. if so remove it.

The next thing is `the_excerpt()`may use auto generated excerpt. it is said in Wp Codex. what you want to use is the `get_the_excerpt()` method which will retrieve a set custom excerpt.

```
<?php if ( has_excerpt() ) : // Only show custom excerpts not autoexcerpts ?>
    <div class="exceprt-container"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[See get_the_excerpt() reference here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/)